# Vehicle Schema Markup Add Range For Payload?

Tags: range, schema, payload

I'm trying to add a payload range to schemma markup for vehicle, not sure the correct format?

Original:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/", 
      "@type": "Vehicle", 
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Name",
      "brand": "Brand Name",
      "model": "Model Name",
      "name": "Vehicle Full Name",
      "image": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
      "color": "Bespoke",
      "mileageFromOdometer": "0",
      "vehicleTransmission": "Manual or Automatic",
      "payload": "2000",
      "url": "https://www.example.com/productpage",
      "offers": {
      "@type": "AggregateOffer",
      "lowPrice": "38995",
      "highPrice": "41995",
      "priceCurrency": "GBP"
    }
    }
    </script>
```

I tried like this for a payload range but it doesn't seem to be the correct syntax:

```
      "payload": {
      "minValue": "1000",
      "maxValue": "2000",
      "unitCode" "KGM",
      }
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, think I just had a typo in my code:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/", 
  "@type": "Vehicle", 
  "manufacturer": "Name of manufacturer",
  "brand": "Name of brand",
  "model": "Model name",
  "name": "Full name of vehicle",
  "image": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
  "description": "Some description here",
  "color": "Bespoke",
  "mileageFromOdometer": "0",
  "vehicleTransmission": "Manual or Automatic",
  "payload": {
  "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
  "minValue": 1000,
  "maxValue": 2000,
  "unitCode": "KGM"
  },
  "url": "https://www.example.com/product",
  "offers": {
  "@type": "AggregateOffer",
  "lowPrice": "38995",
  "highPrice": "41995",
  "priceCurrency": "GBP"
}
}
</script>
```